# SQL SP: Store collection of ids from select query in a TVP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

All I need is to store the list of userids in a TVP named temp in my SQL SP. A single select query will return all the ids required. But my confusion is how can I store it in the TVP temp. As I am the beginner in SQL SP, I Google-d few questions in SO. But they were using the loop. I am not sure how I can use looping in my case.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDetails @mainname nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @mainid int;
    declare #temp table (id int not null)
    select @mainid = id from major where name = @mainname
    select #temp = userid from userTable where mainid = @mainid --Got Stuck here :(

    delete from detailsTable where id in (select * from #temp)
END
GO
```

Any help/suggestion would be useful to me.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific. SQL Server?)

Comment: Its SQL Server 2014

Comment: No reason to use a temp table or table variable ("TVP" is an incorrect and highly misleading term) here - a single delete statement does everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea SMor. I shall check that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare temp table you can create it like normal table.

You can check this script :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDetails 
    @mainname nvarchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mainid int;

    CREATE TABLE #temp 
    (
        id int not null
    )

    SELECT
            @mainid = id
    FROM    major
    WHERE   name = @mainname

    INSERT INTO #temp(id)
    SELECT
            userid
    FROM    userTable
    WHERE   mainid = @mainid 

    DELETE FROM detailsTable
    WHERE id IN (SELECT
                    id
                 FROM #temp
                )
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Just used insert statement here,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDetails @mainname nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @mainid int;
    declare @temp table (id int not null)
    select @mainid = id from major where name = @mainname
    insert into @temp select userid from userTable where mainid = @mainid

    delete from detailsTable where id in (select * from #temp)
END
GO
```

Which solved my problem. Thanks guys.